# Cassandra error AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService

Tags: database, cassandra

I'm trying to use make a CassandraDB mail database, i would like to filter my email. By when i try to filter them, i got this error :

```
ReadFailure: Error from server: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures" info={'failures': 1, 'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
```

I try to know more about this error in the logs in /var/log/cassandra/system.log :

```
WARN  [ReadStage-2] 2018-09-10 18:23:52,079  AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:167 - Uncaught exception on thread Thread[ReadStage-2,10,main]: {}
java.lang.AssertionError: null
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.BTreeRow.getCell(BTreeRow.java:218) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.conf.ColumnIndex.getValueOf(ColumnIndex.java:252) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.plan.Operation.localSatisfiedBy(Operation.java:215) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.plan.Operation.satisfiedBy(Operation.java:145) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.plan.QueryPlan$ResultIterator.computeNext(QueryPlan.java:124) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.plan.QueryPlan$ResultIterator.computeNext(QueryPlan.java:71) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:47) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.BasePartitions.hasNext(BasePartitions.java:92) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.UnfilteredPartitionIterators$Serializer.serialize(UnfilteredPartitionIterators.java:303) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadResponse$LocalDataResponse.build(ReadResponse.java:167) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadResponse$LocalDataResponse.<init>(ReadResponse.java:160) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadResponse$LocalDataResponse.<init>(ReadResponse.java:156) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadResponse.createDataResponse(ReadResponse.java:76) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadCommand.createResponse(ReadCommand.java:346) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$LocalReadRunnable.runMayThrow(StorageProxy.java:1886) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$DroppableRunnable.run(StorageProxy.java:2594) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:162) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$LocalSessionFutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:134) [apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:109) [apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
```

This is my table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE mail__mail (
    accountid uuid,
    date timestamp,
    mailfrom text,
    subject text,
    size bigint,
    id uuid,
    attachment set<uuid>,
    categories set<uuid>,
    content text,
    dateadded timestamp,
    folderid uuid,
    hash text,
    isconfidential boolean,
    isdeleted boolean,
    isimportant boolean,
    isseen boolean,
    mailcc text,
    mailid text,
    mailto text,
    PRIMARY KEY (accountid, date, id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (date DESC);

CREATE CUSTOM INDEX mailFromIndex ON mail__mail (mailfrom) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' WITH OPTIONS = {'mode': 'CONTAINS','analyzed': 'true', 'analyzer_class': 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.analyzer.NonTokenizingAnalyzer', 'case_sensitive': 'false'};
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX subjectIndex ON mail__mail (subject) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' WITH OPTIONS = {'mode': 'CONTAINS','analyzed': 'true', 'analyzer_class': 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.analyzer.NonTokenizingAnalyzer', 'case_sensitive': 'false'};
```

And here is the query creating the error :

```
SELECT * FROM mail__mail WHERE accountid=*UUID* AND folderid=*UUID* AND categories CONTAINS *UUID* AND subject LIKE '%*TEXT*%' LIMIT 50 ALLOW FILTERING;
```

Here is some sample data:

```
accountid                            | date                            | id                                   | attachment | categories | content             | dateadded                       | folderid                             | hash                                                             | isconfidential | isdeleted | isimportant | isseen | mailcc | mailfrom      | mailid | mailto         | size  | subject
-------------------------------------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+--------+--------+---------------+--------+----------------+-------+---------
00321cc1-efef-41f7-a6d8-3d9e38e3e25f | 2018-09-05 08:52:15.000000+0000 | 738424b0-3e47-4dd8-8785-c1e182f4cc84 |       null |       null | <p>test</p>\r\n\r\n | 2018-09-11 14:09:07.112000+0000 | 2f64751c-a53f-4364-8538-3498907d1381 | cda1624bb1ce809a6fd2fa8e5ae6a96c8729d9a7485bbba2aacc56dc31d0fc9e |          False |     False |       False |   True |        | test@test.com |   6522 | test1@test.com | 23481 |    test
00321cc1-efef-41f7-a6d8-3d9e38e3e25f | 2018-09-05 08:50:23.000000+0000 | 32cf8b88-ccef-4c36-abbe-ae13800bc499 |       null |       null | <p>test</p>\r\n\r\n | 2018-09-11 14:09:07.111000+0000 | 2f64751c-a53f-4364-8538-3498907d1381 | dbd23efa7e0aaf9e6174ca06b58e794db70d2980493ebfdd99a499744b79ceca |          False |     False |       False |   True |        | test@test.com |   6521 | test1@test.com | 2729  |    test
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Could you also share some sample data?

Comment: @Horia I add them in an edit, tell me if you need more information

Answer (score 0):

`ALLOW FILTERING` is explicitly allows Cassandra to do a table scan, which is not really good idea due to performance reasons. If you have a lot of records in the table, scanning it can take much more time than it's allowed by your timeouts setup. The solution is to redesign your table in a way it won't require queries with `ALLOW FILTERING`. These should be only for debugging reasons.